# How to manage all application inside tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management

I have some 5 application running in my tomcat server. I want to build some kind of tool where I can be able to choose one application from the application list and than be able to view the following things-

```
 1.)Detect low memory
 2.)Enable or disable GC and class loading verbose tracing
 3.)Detect deadlocks
 4.)Control the log level of any loggers in an application
 5.)Memory used by that application.
 6.)Thread view for that application.
```

I want to have some kind of open source so that i can modify it and integrate it into my web project so that i can view it directly in a webpage.Is there something already existing.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at http://visualvm.java.net

Answer (score 0):

Enable JMX for your Tomcat server: [Monitoring and Managing Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html). Then you can manage it with any JMX console. [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) is the one bundled in JDK.